# Losing the Write permission to windows files from ubuntu 19.04

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, file-sharing

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo along with Windows 10 (Dual Boot). All the last years, mounting the windows partition in Files in Ubuntu I could access all the files and folders in Windows.

Two days ago I deleted a folder in windows partition running Ubuntu. After that now I realized that I do not have any writing permission. I cannot copy to window, delete, or cut. I can just read. My permission in Windows partition is changed in Ubuntu to Read-Only probably, but I did not do that!

How can I have writing access again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than likely your Windows instance enabled fast boot. This means that windows never fully "unmounts" the drives it works with, making other operating systems only able to read them, not write. To bypass this, follow [This guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup), which explains in more detail what fast boot is and how to turn it off.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It perfectly worked. I think the upgrade of windows made the fast startup enable again.